# uipickerview with 2 components delegate

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have the below code for picker with 2 components:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (component == 0) {
    NSLog(@"first");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"second");
}
}
```

the problem is when user try to scroll component 0 first and before waiting for it to completely stop, then scroll component 1 at the same time.

then i will just only have the console log of "second". So it looks like the first event got override by the second event.

is there a way that we can wait for the picker scroll events to complete itself?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem: if the user scrolls component 0, and does not wait it to finish rolling (and start scrolling component 1), that means he does not need to select component 0. Just find a way to set component 0 to it's initial position when component 1 is scrolled before 0 get stopped.

Comment: you have 2 components, declare 2 ints, init them with zero. now, in didSelectRow set these ints accordingly to the selected rows in components. right after setting them, programmatically scroll the pickerview to the rows in these ints. so if a component didnt stop scrolling, it will roll back. just pay attention not to get into an infinite loop here (I fear it could happen)

Comment: let's take the default alarm app as example, when the user setup an alarm, he can at the same time dial through the "hour", and the "minute" component, and when click save, we will get the correct time. But unfortunately i cant get this behavior :(

Comment: you are right... try to nslog just this in didSelectRow: NSLog(@"Component = %i, row = %i", component, row); See what happens, forget about ifs

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to get a two-component UIPickerView to work. As someone suggested, do not use if-statements.

Instead do this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.valueA = [self.valuePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    self.valueB = [self.valuePickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];

    self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", self.valueA, self.valueB];
}
```

Of course if you are looking for an element of an array, just use "objectAtIndex:selectedRowInComponent:0"

---

DO NOT DO THIS:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0){
        self.valueA = ...;
    }
    else if (component == 1){
        self.valueB = ...;
    }

    self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", self.valueA, self.valueB];
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else struggling with this.